# Google map v3 and infobox

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-dialog

Please help me to integrate infobox insted dialog box who use now on my site... You can see the source code here: http://kuponik.adriamart.com/izmena.html What I need to change to put infobox instead dialogbox... i use jquery. I need something like this http://www.mosne.it/playground/mosne_map/#demos (see map#6)

Comment: If you want someone to help you on their own time, make it easier for them. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for tips. Start by clearly saying (1) what you want to do, (2) what you tried to do, and (3) where your problem is. Saying "I have a website, and I want it to be like another website" is missing the entire point of asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [Google Maps Unitility](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) library (InfoBox class). It gives you options to style the box anyway you want. if you asking on how to integrate standard infobox - please read the [Google Maps docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows) - it is a good explanation